# generate js key-value object from string

Tags: javascript, key, key-value

I got a very common question but with a twist which is the reason for this post:

I want to create a key,value object from a string.

my string looks like this:

> 01§§foo§§bar§§someLink

(i can change the delimiter symbols to whatever i want, if there should be somehow a very tight solution with a specific symbol)

now, i want a key value object and most questions about this problem already got the datapair in the string,(like "id:01,title:foo") but thats not the case in my problem.

i want to generate something like this:

```
var modules = [
{"ID":"01", "title":"foo", "description":"bar","link":"someLink"},
//more entries from more strings
];
```

the reason for the key,value object is, that there are more of these strings which I convert from a database. I want it to be in a key,value object so its easier to work with the data later in my tool.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for the string and an array for the keys.

```js
var string = '01§§foo§§bar§§someLink',
    moduleKeys = ["ID", "title", "description", "link"],
    object = {};

string.split('§§').forEach(function (a, i) {
    object[moduleKeys[i]] = a;
});

console.log(object);
```

A methode for multiple strings.

```js
function getData(array) {
    var moduleKeys = ["ID", "title", "description", "link"];
    return array.map(function (string) {
        var object = {};
        string.split('§§').forEach(function (a, i) {
            object[moduleKeys[i]] = a;
        });
        return object;
    });
}

var strings = ['01§§foo§§bar§§someLink', '02§§foo§§bar§§someLink'];
console.log(getData(strings));
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was realy close with my entirley different approach on this and to be fair it was a mess. But thanks to your very simpel and clean solution i discovered the mistake that was giving me a headache: the link in my string cotains "https://[....]" and my brwoser commented everything behind "//"... that was the real issue here.

Comment: Hey, Its me again, how you doing.... it works. The console prints out everything correct, hurray. But when i try to access my object (i named it modules) with modules[0] it say undefined. Therefor i also cant access it with modules[0].ID;  modules[1] is the same

Comment: my `object` is an object, not an array.

Comment: hm thank you again. then i have to ask: how do I convert multiple strings with different content (id:01 to id:x with x = the amount of rows in my database) to objects that are clearly distinguishable? is this even possibl with objects? i guess i got confused quite alot here.